# How do you create a new document in a Sharepoint Document library based on an existing content type using REST?

Tags: javascript, document-library, rest, content-type, file

I have a document library with a content type called 'Letter' attached to it.
The 'Letter' content type has a MS Word document template attached to it.

I would like to know how, using REST, to create a new instance of this content type in my document library, so I end up with a copy of the content type's MS word template document in the document library.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What have you tried sofar and where do you get stuck? This is a place where we share code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've recently had the same need. Unfortunately, I think there's no way to create a new document using REST, because you actually have to UPLOAD something.

In my solution, I made a copy of the template and uploaded it to the library.

```
var templateString = 'yourSite/pathToTemplate/templateName.docx';
var newDocString = 'listInCurrentWeb/newDocumentsName.docx';

copyTo(templateString,newDocString)
    .done(function(data){
            console.log('success: ' + data);    
    })
    .fail(function(error){
            console.log('error: ' + JSON.stringify(error));
    });

function copyTo(sourceFileUrl,targetFileUrl, success,error) {

    var endpointUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/getfilebyserverrelativeurl('" + sourceFileUrl + "')/copyto(strnewurl='" + targetFileUrl + "',boverwrite=false)"; 

    return $.ajax({
            url: endpointUrl,
            method: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
            headers: {   
                "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
                     }, 
                });
}
```

NOTES:

1. When using this method, make sure that `newDocumentsName` is dynamic, because it has to be unique, unless you want to override the existing document with the same name (you can do this by setting `boverwrite` to `true`)
2. You can only use this method to copy items within current web.

I know it's not what you expected, but that's the only solution I came up with after a week of research...

Comment: Thanks Gintas. For any one else reading this - It's worth noting that you can't copy templates from the document set /forms folder. You need to add the templates to a document Library and copy them from there.